# What's the default setting for including a <script> in a post

Tags: plugins, javascript, scripts

As we're evaluating whether we should build a Wordpress plugin and in that context I'm trying to figure out how Wordpress handles script tags in a post?

What's the default setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Scripts shouldn't go inside the body of a post, but it is possible for administrator level users.

See the codex info on [Javascript_in_Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript#Javascript_in_Posts).

If you need JS inside a post, chances are you're approaching it from the wrong angle, content should go in the content area, not code.

However if you're looking to run code when something specific appears in a post, a better approach(imho) is to use a shortcode(or several), you can read more about them [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).